# CLIPS finding most common element across multiple multislot

Tags: clips, expert-system

I'm trying to find the most common element across multiple multislot entry of type symbol and I don't seem to get a decent way to extracts the content of those multislot to single entry to iterate over.

==================================

```
(deftemplate chain "" 
   (multislot edge
      (type SYMBOL))
)

(assert (chain (edge a b c d e f g)))
(assert (chain (edge d e f g h k l)))
(assert (chain (edge e o p q r s f)))

(deffunction find_most_common_edge ()
   (bind ?edge (create$))
   (bind ?counted_edge (create$))
   (bind ?largest_count 0)
   (do-for-all-facts ((?s chain)) TRUE
      (loop-for-count (length$ ?s:edge) (?s1 (expand$ ?s:edge)) 
      (if (not (member$ ?s1 ?counted_edge))
         then
         (bind ?counted_edge (create$ ?s1 ?counted_edge))
         (bind ?count (length$ (find-all-facts ((?s2 chain)) (member$ ?s1 ?s2:edge))))
         (if (= ?count ?largest_count)
            then
            (bind ?edge (create$ ?s1 ?edge))
            else 
            (if (> ?count ?largest_count)
               then
               (bind ?largest_count ?count)
               (bind ?edge (create$ ?s1)))))))      
   (return ?edge))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using functions:

```
         CLIPS (6.4 2/9/21)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate chain
   (multislot edge (type SYMBOL)))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts start
   (chain (edge a b c d e f g))
   (chain (edge d e f g h k l))
   (chain (edge e o p q r s f)))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction get-all-edges ()
   (bind ?all-edges (create$))
   (do-for-all-facts ((?f chain)) TRUE
      (bind ?all-edges (create$ ?all-edges ?f:edge)))
   (return ?all-edges))
CLIPS>    
(deffunction count-edge (?e ?all-edges)
   (bind ?all-length (length$ ?all-edges))
   (return (- ?all-length (length$ (delete-member$ ?all-edges ?e)))))
CLIPS>    
(deffunction remove-duplicates ($?mf)
   (bind ?rv (create$))
   (foreach ?v ?mf
      (if (not (member$ ?v ?rv))
         then 
         (bind ?rv (create$ ?rv ?v))))
   (return ?rv))
CLIPS>      
(deffunction find-most-common-edge ()
   (bind ?all-edges (get-all-edges))
   (bind ?unique-edges (remove-duplicates ?all-edges))
   (bind ?largest-count 0)
   (bind ?most-common (create$))
   (foreach ?e ?unique-edges
      (bind ?count (count-edge ?e ?all-edges))
      (if (= ?count ?largest-count)
         then
         (bind ?most-common (create$ ?most-common ?e))
         else 
         (if (> ?count ?largest-count)
            then
            (bind ?largest-count ?count)
            (bind ?most-common (create$ ?e)))))
   (return ?most-common))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (find-most-common-edge)
(e f)
CLIPS>
```

Using rules:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate chain
   (slot id (default-dynamic (gensym*)))
   (multislot edge (type SYMBOL)))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate count
   (slot edge)
   (multislot ids))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts start
   (chain (edge a b c d e f g))
   (chain (edge d e f g h k l))
   (chain (edge e o p q r s f))
   (find-common-edge))
CLIPS> 
(defrule create-count
   (logical (find-common-edge))
   (chain (id ?id) (edge $? ?e $?))
   (not (count (edge ?e)))
   =>
   (assert (count (edge ?e) (ids ?id))))
CLIPS>    
(defrule add-to-count
   (logical (find-common-edge))
   (chain (id ?id) (edge $? ?e $?))
   ?f <- (count (edge ?e) (ids $?ids))
   (test (not (member$ ?id ?ids)))
   =>
   (modify ?f (ids ?ids ?id)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule most-common-edge
   (declare (salience -10))
   ?f <- (find-common-edge)
   (count (edge ?e) (ids $?r1))
   (not (and (count (edge ~?e) (ids $?r2))
             (test (> (length$ ?r2) (length$ ?r1)))))
   =>
   (bind ?length (length$ ?r1))
   (bind ?edges (create$))
   (do-for-all-facts ((?c count)) 
                     (eq (length$ ?c:ids) ?length)
      (bind ?edges (create$ ?edges ?c:edge)))
   (assert (most-common-edges ?edges))
   (retract ?f))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-1     (chain (id gen4) (edge a b c d e f g))
f-2     (chain (id gen5) (edge d e f g h k l))
f-3     (chain (id gen6) (edge e o p q r s f))
f-20    (most-common-edges e f)
For a total of 4 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, greatly appreciated.